# Nginx error readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream

Tags: http, nginx, get, tomcat7

We have nginx version: nginx/1.6.2 and tomcat 7 as the setup and see these errors in our nginx logs. Can some explain what this error means and if we need to change any settings in our setup to make this work.

```
2015/10/06 11:05:00 [error] 1005#0: *3026220 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 10.144.106.221, server: _, request: "GET /exelate/usersync?
segment=3460,3461,3462,3463,3466,1475,3482,3485,8129,1443,8128,1444,1438,1440,1442,5174,5173,3457,3455,3456,3453,3454,3451,1447,1448,3452,3449,145
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We increased the Http header size for tomcat and this issue has been resolved. We made maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" so that tomcat can accept 64KB headers default is 8KB.

Answer (score 1):

In my Case, it because of Netflix Zuul:

I get this message from nginx log when I try to upload file more than 1 MB:

> readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream

My web application uses Nginx and redirects to Netflix Zuul. So I need to set this configuration in properties.yml of Zuul.

```
servlet:
multipart:
  max-request-size: 10MB
  max-file-size: 10MB
```

And my problem is solved.